# Do I need a 10GbE router to provide 10Gbps LAN speed?

Tags: router, switch, ethernet, 10gbase

We're planning on creating a 10GbE network for our office. I've got a list of hardware that all support 10GbE, only the router isn't 10GbE:

- Synology DS3612+ - 12 Drive NAS
- Intel X540-T1 - 10GbE Network adaptor for NAS
- Netgear XS708E - 10GbE Switch
- SANLink2 - Thunderbolt - 10GbE adapter
- Cat7 Cables

Setup is as folows:

- Our gigabit-router (**NOT** 10GbE) will be connected to the Switch
- Computers will be connected to the Switch via SANLink2
- The NAS will be connected to the Switch via 10GbE adaptor

What I'd like to know:

- Will the computers be able to connect to the NAS at 10GbE?
- Will the router slow things (other than internet) down?
- Any other drawbacks?

**EDIT:**

The needs for this network are the following:

- We want to do 4K video-editing directly from the NAS.
- We want to transfer 2TB of data to the NAS in less than an hour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Will the computers be able to connect to the NAS at 10GbE?***

Yes, if both the computers and the NAS are connected to the switch at 10GbE and do not require routing (ie. both are in the same subnet and VLAN).

***Will the router slow things (other than internet) down?***

It will slow anything which passes through it down to gigabit, but only if is faster to begin with.

***Any other drawbacks?***

This could be the perfect setup for you, but it could also fail to deliver under certain conditions. Since we don't know what it has to deliver, it's hard to tell.  It all depends on how you will use it and what you expect from it...

Comment: Thanks for the answers to all the questions. The network has to deliver a solution which makes it possible to do 4K video-editing directly from the NAS. Also it needs to be able to transfer 2TB of files in less than an hour.

Comment: You might be stopped by the limitations of the drive's write/read rather than the speed of the network.

Answer (score 4):

As long as all workstations are on the same VLAN as the NAS, you won't need a 10Gig router.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know the exact meaning of VLAN, but I guess I can find that out.. I assume I don't need any more hardware to get things to work..

Comment: Switches are usually set to a single VLAN out of the box.
It should be fairly plug and play.

Comment: Thanks Tim, same question and same confusion about VLAN and managed vs unmanaged switches. Can anyone give an example of a 10Gbps switch that would *not* support the faster speed in this scenario? Or a common networking scenario where the machines would be on a separate VLAN and therefore have to go through the slower router?

Answer (score -2):

XS708E is an unmanaged switch so there would be no VLANS

Comment: The documentation and the Netgear website contradict your answer. [Data sheet](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/datasheet/en/XS708E.pdf)

Comment: True that. Specs: http://www.netgear.com/images/DS_XS708_18Jan13v318-71681.pdf. Funny enough it shows up under "Unmanaged switches"...